# Number of times PostgreSQL database restarted

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

How to get how many times my PostgreSQL database restarted and how to get each restart time?

I do not want to get the details from the log file. Is there any other way to get those details?

Comment: A restart doesn't generate a new log file. You'll have to read them all.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the `pg_log` or any PG log files, using `grep` to match *how many times of shutting down the database*.

```
grep -rwn postgresql-2018-04-12.log -e "database system is shut down"
```

The output looks like as below

> postgresql-2018-04-12.log:9:2018-04-12 16:07:25 CEST LOG:  database
>   system is shut down postgresql-2018-04-12.log:18:2018-04-12 16:08:18
>   CEST LOG:  database system is shut down

Answer (score 1):

Just head to log director of postgresql on which all restart session are logged in 
default directoy

`cd /var/log/postgresql/`

Now grep the log file with the below command to know when database was shutdown

`grep "shutdown" postgresql-9.1-main.log`

grep the log file with the below command to know when database was started

`grep "starting" postgresql-9.1-main.log`